# HTTP call from Celery worker

Tags: docker, http, kubernetes, redis, celery

I am running a Flask-Celery server in docker desktop Kubernetes. It uses a Redis Result Backend.

I want to use a Celery Task to make an HTTP call to a program that might take a while. This program returns a result that I want to store somewhere so that the user is able to retrieve it with an HTTP call to Celery.

How do I go about this? 
Should I make the Task wait for the HTTP call to finish? 
Is this good practice? 
How do I make sure the result is stored in the Result Backend?

This is what my code currently looks like for one Celery task:

```py
@celery.task(name="calculate", acks_late=True) 
def calculate(headers):     
    calculationService = "flask-calculation-service.default:4000"            
    url = "http://" + calculationService + "/startCalculation"      
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))     
    responseString = response.json()          
    return responseString
```

This is how my 'start calculation' and 'poll for result' routes are defined:

```py
@app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST']) 
def Calculation_route():    
    #make headers        
    async_result = calculate.delay(headers)     
    return jsonify({"PollUrl":"/poll/"+async_result.id})  

@app.route('/poll/<poll_id>') 
def get_result(poll_id):     
    res = AsyncResult(poll_id,app=celery)      
    if isinstance(res.result, RuntimeError):
        result = str(res.result)      
    else:      
        if res.ready():         
            result = jsonify(res.result)       
        else:       
            result = jsonify({"status":res.status})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem particularly specific to running the worker in a container.  How would you do this without Docker?  (...with `requests.get(url)`?)  What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have 4 components to your architecture:

- a client that makes requests to an app server
- an app server that serves results of some computation
- a celery worker pool that requests the calculations
- a calculation service that does the heavy processing and takes time

Right now, your client calls the server, at the `/calculate` endpoint, and that triggers a celery task on a worker, and immediately returns a job id to the client. The client is then in charge of polling the server until results are available.

The celery worker makes a POST request to the calculation service which is synchronous, so the worker waits for the response, then stores it in a DB.

When the job is done, results are available, and the client polling for results get served the results.

So, if the goal is not to overwhelm the calculation service, it serves the purpose. However like you said, the celery worker is mostly idle, and it is the component holding the queue of requests from the client.

To improve on this model, you could push the celery worker queue system into your calculation service rather than the app server, and have:

- a client making calculation requests
- an app server proxying requests to a calculation server
- a calculation server that queues up calculation tasks
- a celery worker pool that performs the calculations

In that case, the client calls the app server, the app server forwards the request to the calculation service (act as a proxy). The calculation service receives the request and queues up the task with the celery worker queue, and returns a job id immediately.

The calculation task gets picked up by the celery worker, and stores the results when it is done. This time the celery worker is the one doing the heavy-lifting.

The app server just proxies the requests.

Ideally, you may improve further, and even get rid of the calculation server altogether; if all it does is receive requests to queue tasks, you can integrate this function within the app server (as you do now, except instead of calling a service, the worker does the job itself).

In this case what you need is to scale the celery worker pool according to the queue size. In that case you end up with:

- a client making calculation requests
- an app server that queues up calculation tasks
- a celery worker pool that performs the calculations

In short, if you own/manage that calculation code (as the sample seems to suggest), instead of making a POST call to a service and wait for data, put the calculation code directly into the celery worker.

For parallelism, that will depend on how many celery workers you deploy to listen to the queue. Each worker will pick up tasks in the queue in order and process them. The more workers, the faster you will process all the requests that are queued in (if as you say they are all queued in at once)

Another option you could consider to avoid the polling for result, is to re-imagine the REST server and use Websockets. The client would connect to the websocket and send the calculate request. The celery task run and would notify the server when a task is done (through another websocket channel), and the server can go fetch the result and push it down to the client through the client websocket.

That avoids the constant polling, but is a little bit more complex to implement. It also requires to re-work the client side of things to listen to the data being returned rather than poll, but I think that is more elegant.

Regarding tasks and order, note that here you only show 1 task, but I imagine you may have more. If you have task that need to run in order, beware that parallelism might cause issues. If you have a 2-steps process and step 2 depends on step 1, a worker could pick up step 1 an another pick up step 2 and you might get inconsistent results. Celery has a mechanism to define dependencies and insure this doesn't happen.

Also, if your client makes multiple consecutive calculate requests, and you only care about the latest, you might want to implement task cancelation to avoid processing tasks unnecessarily.

Comment: I want to implement Celery because when there are a lot of requests coming in at the same time, the Flask server pods of the long-running calculation get overwhelmed, and requests are ignored. The idea behind the Celery-workers is that waiting for the calculation to end does not use up many CPU resources (I assume), so requests can always come in, regardless of how many there are. (I realize there are also constraints but much higher than the current implementation, I presume). The Flask-Celery implementation serves as a way to separate the request-handling and calculation concerns.

Comment: ```@celery.task(name="calculate", acks_late=True)
def calculate(headers):
    calculationService = "flask-calculation-service.default:4000"       
    url = "http://" + calculationService + "/startCalculation"

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    responseString = response.json()
    
    return responseString
 ```
 
This is what my code currently looks like for one Celery task. It does seem to work fine. It saves the result in a Postgresql and my external C# code can poll Celery for the result based on an ID. I apologize  for the ugly format

Comment: so, if i understand your architecture, you're using celery to queue the jobs and make sure there are not too many requests at once. Is there any kind of level of parallelism there at all, or is it a FIFO?

Comment: ```@app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def StartGeneticAlgorithmByIdDataIncluded_route():

 #make headers
 
    async_result = calculate.delay(headers)
    return jsonify({"PollUrl":"/poll/"+async_result.id})

@app.route('/poll/<poll_id>')
def get_result(poll_id):
    res = AsyncResult(poll_id,app=celery)

    if isinstance(res.result, RuntimeError):
        result = str(res.result) 
    else:
        if res.ready():
            result = jsonify(res.result)
        else:
            result = jsonify({"status":res.status})
```

Comment: This is how my 'start calculation' and 'poll for result' routes are defined. With the previous piece of code I sent you, this shows the full round-trip a request makes. 
First my C# program starts the calculation by calling the '/calculate' route. It gets back an Id that it can then use to poll for the result every 5 seconds on the '/poll/<poll_id>' route.
The reason that I want to do it like this is because when all requests go to "http://" + calculationService + "/startCalculation" straight away, the CalculationService Flask pods get overwhelmed and start dropping requests.

Comment: As for parallelism, my understanding is that Celery-workers have some concurrency built in? If this is not the case, would it be an option to run 100 small workers at the same time so that 100 requests can be handled at the same time?
Since the only task of the workers is to wait for a response to 'requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))', I think these workers can have a small cpu and memory requirements, so this seems like a possibility? (Again, apologies for the format of the code). Thanks for responding!

Comment: see edit on my answer

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I am not sure what you mean with "you don't let an HTTP call wait a long time for the data to return, which would certainly overwhelm your server." Will my celery workers also get overwhelmed? I use them as a polling-system between my pods that do a heavy calculation and my C# program I am running locally. But the workers themselves just wait for the request to the calculation-pods to finish before storing the result in postgresql (as you can see in my '@celery.task(name="calculate", acks_late=True' code block)